# Provider is not updating variable when back to the screen

Tags: flutter

I have the following onTap function on screen A:

```
onTap: () async { 
  cambiarEspecialidadIdForo(especialidad.id_especialidad);
  cambiarEspecialidadIconoForo(especialidad.icono_especialidad);
  _esEsp ? cambiarEspecialidadNombreForo(especialidad.nombre_especialidad) : cambiarEspecialidadNombreForo(especialidad.nombre_especialidad_en);
  if(_esEsp){
    Provider.of<ForoProvider>(context,listen: false).cambiarNumeroMensajesForo16espVistos(Provider.of<ForoProvider>(context,listen: false).numMensajesForoEsp16); 
  }
       
  if(!_esEsp){ 
    Provider.of<ForoProvider>(context,listen: false).cambiarNumeroMensajesForo16engVistos(Provider.of<ForoProvider>(context,listen: false).numMensajesForoEng16);
  }
                
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MensajesForoScreen(especialidad: especialidad)));
},
```

And on the same screen, there is a Text widget:

```
Text("${Provider.of<ForoProvider>(context).numMensajesForoEsp16Vistos} / ${Provider.of<ForoProvider>(context).numMensajesForoEsp16}",    style:
                                                                TextStyle(fontSize: 16,color: hexStringToColor(especialidad.color_especialidad))),


Provider.of<ForoProvider>(context).numMensajesForoEsp16 is 5,
Provider.of<ForoProvider>(context).numMensajesForoEsp16Visto is 0 as default, but after onTap it changes to 5
```

When executing the onTap function, the value of `Provider.of<ForoProvider>(context).numMensajesForoEsp16Vistos` changes to 5 (correct, new text is 5/5, first it was 0/5) in the text widget and then the screen MensajesForoScreen is shown, but then, on going back again to screen A, the value for `Provider.of<ForoProvider>(context).numMensajesForoEsp16Vistos` is not updated and the Text shows 0/5 again.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should use `notifyListeners();` in `numMensajesForoEsp16Vistos` function. you can call `Provider.of<ForoProvider>(context).numMensajesForoEsp16Vistos` function in [WillPopScope](https://flutterrettulf.com/navigation/2022/09/03/how-to-use-willpopscope-widget-in-flutter-with-examples.html) to update Text Widget. and you can use [Consumer](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Consumer-class.html) instead of

```
Text("${Provider.of<ForoProvider>(context).numMensajesForoEsp16Vistos} / ${Provider.of<ForoProvider>(context).numMensajesForoEsp16}",    style:
                                                                TextStyle(fontSize: 16,color: hexStringToColor(especialidad.color_especialidad))),
```

Comment: I am using notifylisteners in  ForoProvider

Comment: void cambiarNumeroMensajesForo16espVistos (int s){
    numMensajesForoEsp16Vistos = s;
    notifyListeners();
  }